# Cloud9: Could not find an open port

Tags: node.js, npm, port, cloud9-ide, netstat

I'm new to NodeJS and trying to set up an existing project (developed by someone else) in Cloud9 IDE (I'm using an older Cloud9 account; so not running on AWS). I've pulled the git and installed everything. This all seemed to go without problems.

To run the app locally, outside of Cloud9, you would start the server with `npm run start` (I know from the person who developed the app, this works for him). But I want to set it up in Cloud9, and in Cloud9 it is necessary to set some variables first (if I don't define the host first, it gives the error "Invalid Host header"). Therefore, I use the following two commands:

```
export HOST=$C9_HOSTNAME && export PORT=8080
npm run start
```

The `npm run start` produces the error:

> Could not find an open port at appname-username.c9users.io.
>
> Network error message: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 35.189.252.103

I believe I have the port correct, considering https://docs.c9.io/docs/run-an-application. I’ve also tried the values 8081, 8082 and $PORT but none of these work.

Any ideas how I could get the Cloud9 local preview working?

---

Upon request some lines from `start.js`:

```
const DEFAULT_PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const HOST = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';
console.log(`1. The host is ${HOST} on port ${DEFAULT_PORT}`);  //ADDED

choosePort(HOST, DEFAULT_PORT)
  .then(port => {
    console.log(`2. The host is ${HOST} on port ${DEFAULT_PORT}`);  //ADDED
    if (port == null) {
      // We have not found a port.
      return;
    }
    const protocol = process.env.HTTPS === 'true' ? 'https' : 'http';
    const appName = require(paths.appPackageJson).name;
    const urls = prepareUrls(protocol, HOST, port);
    // Create a webpack compiler that is configured with custom messages.
    const compiler = createCompiler(webpack, config, appName, urls, useYarn);
    // Load proxy config
    const proxySetting = require(paths.appPackageJson).proxy;
    const proxyConfig = prepareProxy(proxySetting, paths.appPublic);
    // Serve webpack assets generated by the compiler over a web sever.
    const serverConfig = createDevServerConfig(
      proxyConfig,
      urls.lanUrlForConfig
    );
    const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, serverConfig);
    // Launch WebpackDevServer.
    devServer.listen(port, HOST, err => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      if (isInteractive) {
        clearConsole();
      }
      console.log(chalk.cyan('Starting the development server...\n'));
      openBrowser(urls.localUrlForBrowser);
    });

  })
  .catch(err => {
    if (err && err.message) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

`netstat --listen` responds with the following information:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1533837857 /home/ubuntu/.c9/6614254/collab.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1533835235 /home/ubuntu/.c9/bridge.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1533836998 /tmp/tmux-1000/cloud92.2
```

The function `choosePort` is part of the node module "react-dev-utils" and reads as follows:

```
function choosePort(host, defaultPort) {
  return detect(defaultPort, host).then(
    port => new Promise(resolve => {
      if (port === defaultPort) {
        return resolve(port);
      }
      if (isInteractive) {
        clearConsole();
        const existingProcess = getProcessForPort(defaultPort);
        const question = {
          type: 'confirm',
          name: 'shouldChangePort',
          message: chalk.yellow(
            `Something is already running on port ${defaultPort}.` +
              `${existingProcess ? ` Probably:\n  ${existingProcess}` : ''}`
          ) + '\n\nWould you like to run the app on another port instead?',
          default: true,
        };
        inquirer.prompt(question).then(answer => {
          if (answer.shouldChangePort) {
            resolve(port);
          } else {
            resolve(null);
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log(
          chalk.red(`Something is already running on port ${defaultPort}.`)
        );
        resolve(null);
      }
    }),
    err => {
      throw new Error(
        chalk.red(`Could not find an open port at ${chalk.bold(host)}.`) +
          '\n' +
          ('Network error message: ' + err.message || err) +
          '\n'
      );
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: If you can't find how to preview your running app, try to use port 8080 in the URL.

Comment: Thanks @RamThakur, but I'm afraid I don't fully understand what you mean. Do you mean to first run `export HOST=$C9_HOSTNAME:8080` and then `npm run start`? This produces a similar error: "Could not find an open port at appname-username.c9users.io:8080".

Comment: Can we get access to the node.js code? It might be the case that the node.js server is specifying a static port in code instead of adhering to the `PORT` environment variable you are setting prior to starting the app.

Comment: @willascend, I have added what I think is the relevant part of the code to the post.

Comment: I just scanned the IP address you provided with nmap and 8080 is open. Are you sure you have the correct hostname and application name?

Comment: Since I use `export HOST=$C9_HOSTNAME` I know I'm not making any typos. Also, `echo $HOST` confirms export worked correctly. 
I added two console.log lines to `start.js`  (see post). The first console.log returns `1. The host is appname-username.c9users.io on port 8080` as we would expect. The second console.log line is never reached since it goes to the `catch(err...` part of the code.

Comment: @Nick actually I was trying to say that can you open the URL with port 8080 in a different tab after pressing the run button on the top right which is along with preview button. 
for e.g- 
appname-username.c9users.io:8080

Comment: @RamThakur, pressing the run button is the same as `npm run start`, which results in the described error message.

Comment: @Nick the fact that you're never reaching the second console.log is good information. The code is failing somewhere in the choosePort function. Can you paste that function's body as well?

Comment: Thanks @willascend, I've added the function to the original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some googling on this and I think the issue might be with the host value you are setting. Per [this Cloud9 support thread](https://community.c9.io/t/node-js-eaddrnotavail-wrong-ip-address-solved/16137/3) which references a similar error:

> ...You need to use 0.0.0.0 instead since c9user.io is the public address of the proxy. Or modify your /etc/hosts file. echo "0.0.0.0 $C9_HOSTNAME" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts

So, try setting the host to 0.0.0.0 instead of the public hostname:

```
export HOST=0.0.0.0 && export PORT=8080 && npm run start
```

Also just found this on the [support page](https://docs.c9.io/docs/run-an-application) you linked to:

> If you're developing a server application, please note that you need to listen to 0.0.0.0 ($IP) and 8080 ($PORT). Listening to this port will enable your app to be viewable at http://-.c9users.io

Listening on 0.0.0.0 should resolve the issue.

Edit (in response to additional error being returned):

For the "Invalid host header" error, I think you're on the right track with setting `disableHostCheck` to true, but your npm script command isn't likely adhering to the flag from.the CLI. There are probably a few ways to get that flag passed, but the simplest might be to update your code to set the option when creating the dev server. Keep in mind this is just a quick fix to see if we can get it to work. It would be better to update the `createDevServerConfig` function to set the option:

```
const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, { ...serverConfig, disableHostCheck: true});
```

Another edit:

The disableHostCheck option is insecure and can open you up to vulnerabilities. It's considered a quick fix when testing locally and should only be used in a closed network. To fix the"Invalid host header" in an exposed environment, use the `public` option, where public is your DNS host name or public IP address:

```
const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, { ...serverConfig, public: process.env.PUBLIC_HOST }
```

You can then have this value passed in via the CLI environment like your other vars:

```
export HOST=0.0.0.0 && export PORT=8080 && export PUBLIC_HOST=$C9_HOSTNAME:8080 && npm run start
```

Disclaimer: I don't think the changes above are the best way to go about doing this (it would likely be better to update the `createDevServerConfig` function, but they should resolve your issues. More information on the `disableHostCheck` option can be found [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/releases/tag/v2.4.3), [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/882), and [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-public).

Comment: Thanks, I enter `export HOST=0.0.0.0 && export PORT=8080 && npm run start`. Then I visit appname-username.c9users.io:8080. This produces the error "Invalid Host header". 
On https://help.crossbrowsertesting.com/faqs/testing/invalid-host-header-error/ I read this is “most commonly caused by a misconfiguration of the application server that causes it to reject non-local connections.”.
I tried `npm run start --disable-host-check`. This however still results in "Invalid Host header".

Comment: Hi @Nick. I edited my answer. If what I provided doesn't work, you night need to update the `createDevServerConfig` function. Also, depending on what the `npm run start` script actually is, it may be possible to update it and add the CLI option there.

Comment: If I change it to `const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {serverConfig, disableHostCheck: true});` it gives the error "Invalid configuration object. webpack-dev-server has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema. - configuration has an unknown property 'serverConfig'."   I also tried `const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, serverConfig, {disableHostCheck: true});` but then it doesn't seem to process `disableHostCheck` as it it still gives the "Invalid Host Header" error.

Comment: Hi Nick, did you add the three dots in front of the `serverConfig` identifier in the object? I updated the code there was a typo. Please see if what's there now will work.

Comment: Thanks, awesome, it now works! Is there also a way to disable the HostCheck without makes changes to the code? (it sounds a bit insecure, so if someone else working with the code doesn't need to disable it to make it run locally, I'm sure they would prefer not to have this disabled.)

Comment: Hi @Nick, code or configuration changes will be required to resolve this issue. Can you open a pull request on the original repo? With that said, you are correct about the security vulnerability. I've updated my answer to also include the `public` option, which should be used when proxying the server. Will that resolve your issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185913/discussion-between-willascend-and-nick).

Comment: Great! Glad I could help!